# How to perform quick upleveling in python?

Tags: python

I have the following object in python:

```
{
   name: John,
   age: {
     years:18
   },
   computer_skills: {
     years:4
   },
   mile_runner: {
     years:2
   }
}
```

I have an array with 100 people with the same structure.

What is the best way to go through all 100 people and make it such that there is no more "years"? In other words, each object in the 100 would look something like:

```
{
   name: John,
   age:18,
   computer_skills:4,
   mile_runner:2
}
```

I know I can do something in pseudocode:

```
for(item in list):
  if('years' in (specific key)):
     specifickey = item[(specific key)][(years)]
```

But is there a smarter/more efficent way?

Comment: I don't think there's a "smarter way" than going through and changing them, unless you want to make a new dict, in which case you could use a comprehension. Not much smarter, imho, but at that point it's aesthetics unless you have a business need to keep/discard the old version.

Comment: What kind of object is that? Why are "name", "John", etc not quoted? How are we supposed to try this if it's not even close to syntactically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is already pretty good I think:

```
for person in persons:
    for k, v in person.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict) and 'years' in v:
            person[k] = v['years']
```

This overwrites every property which is a dictionary that has a `years` property with that property’s value.

Unlike other solutions (like dict comprehensions), this will modify the object in-place, so no new memory to keep everything is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(d):
    ret = {}
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and len(value) == 1 and "years" in value:
            ret[key] = value["years"]
        else:
            ret[key] = value
    return ret

d = {
   "name": "John",
   "age": {
     "years":18
   },
   "computer_skills": {
     "years":4
   },
   "mile_runner": {
     "years":2
   }
}

print flatten(d)
```

Result:

```
{'age': 18, 'mile_runner': 2, 'name': 'John', 'computer_skills': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
import json
with open("input.json") as f:
  cont = json.load(f)
  print {el:cont[el]["years"] if "years" in cont[el] else cont[el] for el in cont}
```

prints

```
{u'age': 18, u'mile_runner': 2, u'name': u'John', u'computer_skills': 4}
```

where `input.json` contains

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age": {
     "years":18
   },
   "computer_skills": {
     "years":4
   },
   "mile_runner": {
     "years":2
   }
}
```

Linear with regards to number of elements, you can't really hope for any lower.

Answer (score 0):

As people said in the comments, it isn't exactly clear what your "object" is, but assuming that you actually have a list of dicts like this:

```
list = [{
   'name': 'John',
   'age': {
     'years': 18
   },
   'computer_skills': {
     'years':4
   },
   'mile_runner': {
     'years':2
   }
}]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
for item in list:
    for key in item:
        try:
            item[key] = item[key]['years']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            pass
```

Result:

```
list = [{'age': 18, 'mile_runner': 2, 'name': 'John', 'computer_skills': 4}]
```